# Convert to PDO mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have some problems when i try to convert system to PDO_MYSQL. 
I tried to convert this line:

```
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM accounts WHERE name='$username' AND password='$password';"), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
```

to something like:

```
$sth = $dbc1->PDOPrepare("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM accounts WHERE name='$username' AND password='$password';");
$sth->execute();
return $sth->fetchColumn();
```

But i know it is not correct, it not works as well. So, can someone more experienced have a look at it? I don't get the piece `== 1) ? $user_id : false;` .. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
Worked with `return $sth->fetchColumn() ? $user_id : false;`

Comment: Nevermind, worked with return $sth->fetchColumn() ? $user_id : false;

Comment: You are not even using the actual function names... Have you read anything about PDO in the manual or checked the available examples?

Comment: This are custom functions

Comment: So you have code we cannot see, and it doesn't work in a way we're not told. No, I don't think we can have a look a it.

Comment: It's saying if $dbc1 equals 1 (true) then return the user_id otherwise return false.

Comment: Thanks Ant, great to know. I updated main post with the solve for the problem. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using "custom functions"? That's making a mess of things.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what `PDOPrepare` does in your program; but you're going for the prepared statements in the wrong manner. Try the following:

```
$sth = $dbc1->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM accounts WHERE name = ? AND password = ?");
$sth->execute( array($username, $password) );
return ( intval($sth->fetchColumn()) == 1 ) ? $user_id : false;;
```

Please note that I've changed `PDOPrepare` with just [`prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) since that is the class method for PDO.

Comment: I updated main post with the solve for the problem. Thanks